Unity: Creating buttons in for loop without all having same onClick parameter
I am making an inventory system, so I want each button onClick to call a function with a unique integer per button, so it knows which slot is being clicked. Below is my code:
public int inventorySize = 32;
public GameObject slotPrefab;
public GameObject slotHolder;
private int curSlotId = 0;

    public void InitiateMenu()
    {
        inventory.Initialize();
        for (int i = 0; i < inventorySize; i++)
        {
            GameObject newSlot = Instantiate(slotPrefab);
            newSlot.transform.SetParent(slotHolder.transform, false);
            //Change onClick
            newSlot.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { SlotClick(curSlotId); });
            curSlotId++;
        }
    }

    public void SlotClick(int slot)
    {
        Debug.Log("Inventory Slot #" + slot.ToString());
    }

Whatever I do, it seems that all buttons when clicked write "Inventory Slot #32" to the Debug.Log, I have tried using just the i variable in the for loop, which warranted the same issue. How would you go about doing this? It seems however I initiate or place the variable it reads the same memory space every single for loop, making all the buttons call the function with the integer 32.
I know many people don't like when Unity questions are asked with the 'C#' tag but I wonder if this is a C# thing, not a Unity thing. Please excuse me if I am wrong.

Does this answer your question? Captured variable in a loop in C#

Probably the issue is because you are passing the reference of "curSlotId" and by the end of the loop you reach the index 32 and that's the last value the "curSlotId" has. As @BugFinder suggestion post says, you should create a local copy of the value inside the loop and pass it to your lambda expression or method.

The problem with your code is that the curSlotId is captured by reference by the delegate, so all the delegate functions end up using the same value, which is the value of the curSlotId when the loop finishes (which is 32), To fix this, you can create a local variable inside the loop and assign the current value of curSlotId to it.
Here is the Fixed Code :
public void InitiateMenu()
{
    inventory.Initialize();
    for (int i = 0; i < inventorySize; i++)
    {
        int slotId = curSlotId; //local variable
        GameObject newSlot = Instantiate(slotPrefab);
        newSlot.transform.SetParent(slotHolder.transform, false);
        newSlot.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { SlotClick(slotId); }); // Use the local variable
        curSlotId++;
    }
}


You need separate functions.
Look up c# reflection to create a clone of your function if you want to write your function once, but replicate it separately.
Get method info
MethodInfo mInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod("SlotClick");  // inside the loop!!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=net-8.0
I didn't test this code yet.
public class ShieldButton {
    public string ButtonImg;
    public void activateSheild() {
       // ...
    };   
}

public class Button {
    // this is the method we will methos info with!
    // we are going to change the method parameters in the for loop when cloning.
    // then we will invoke the cloned method..
    public void click<T>(T Type) {
        switch (typeOf(Type)) {
            case ShieldButton: { Type.activateShield() };
        }
    }
}

public class CreateMenu {
    public void InitiateMenu()
{
    inventory.Initialize();
    for (int i = 0; i < inventorySize; i++)
    {
        MethodInfo mInfo = typeof(Button).GetMethod("click"); // Grab the class and method!
        MethodInfo newInfo = mInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ShieldButton)); // make a clone of the method changing the parameter type to our ShieldButton Class!
        ShieldButton shieldButton = new ShieldButton(); // Create a new version of the shield button class
        GameObject newSlot = Instantiate(slotPrefab);
        newSlot.transform.SetParent(slotHolder.transform, false);
        newSlot.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(newInfo.Invoke(null, shieldButton)); // Invoke the new methodInfo passing in the class to switch on!!!!
    }
  }
}

Pro'er Tip: Iterate with an object or an array of buttons instead of a for loop. This way you can select the proper type for the new method info.

This makes no sense at all. MethodInfo represent static meta data that is generated when the code is compiled. Using MemberwiseClone on a MethodInfo does not create a new method. It just duplicates the metadata info for no reason.

The MethodInfo class represents a method of a type. You can use a MethodInfo object to obtain information about the method that the object represents and to invoke the method. Create a class. Grab the method info of your function. Clone it. And invoke it…. The person above clearly doesn’t understand c# programming….
